# SQL find only records with date older than

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `InventTrans`

Columns:

```
itemid, datephysical, recordid
```

I need to find only itemid which have date datephysical older than 01-01-2016 and not exist any newer.

I'm trying this way- but its not work correctly.

```
select ITEMID 
from INVENTTRANS itra
where itra.DATEPHYSICAL <= CONVERT(datetime, '2016-01-01') 
and ITEMID not in (
    select itemid 
    from INVENTTRANS 
    where itra.DATEPHYSICAL >= CONVERT(datetime, '2016-01-01')
)
group by ITEMID
```

Comment: "not work correctly", in which way? Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: The subquery condition looks suspicious.

Comment: To paraphrase your query, you want all `ITEMID`s that have ***at least one row*** with a `DATEPHYSICAL <= '2016-01-01'` and ***zero rows*** with a  `DATEPHYSICAL >= '2016-01-01'`?  If so, what's not working for you?  Error messages, unexpected results?  Can you create a dummy data-set to demonstrate the issues you're experiencing, so that we can replicate them?  Also, telling us the indexes that exist would help us demonstrate a permformant solution.

Comment: You dont need `group by` , use `Distinct` instead. What is datatype of column `itra.DATEPHYSICAL', is it datetime or varchar. Add some sample  
 data

Comment: I've spotted the issue.  The sub-query states `where itra.DATEPHYSICAL >=` which refers to the outer query.  It should simply be `where DATEPHYSICAL >=`.  Though the answers below a likely better approaches that yours.

Comment: Just read the second comment!

Comment: I need to select only records where NOT EXISTS any record after 2016-01-01. 

Because:
I want to delete all itemid which wasn't used last two years.

Comment: @jarlh - Your second comment is vague, you should explicitly point out what particular aspect of the condition is suspicious, why it's suspicious, what the alternative is, etc ;)

Comment: @ MatBailie - exactly. Not working because results is still showing some lines with DATEPHYSICAL >= '2016-01-01'.

Comment: @MatBailie, intentionally vague. When someone doesn't make much effort describing the problem, I don't hurry giving the correct answer.

Comment: Thank to all for your effort - I was slow in data preparation. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `HAVING` to verify the max date is before 2016-01-01.

```
select ITEMID 
from INVENTTRANS itra
group by ITEMID
HAVING MAX(DATEPHYSICAL) < CONVERT(datetime, '2016-01-01')
```

Comment: @MatBailie, the sub-query condition in OP's query is correlated, it should be uncorrelated.

Comment: Then you should say that in the answer ;)

Comment: Works great :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `where not exists`

```
select distinct ITEM_ID
from INVENTTRANS t1
where DATEPHYSICAL  < cast('2016-01-01' as date)
and not exists 
  (
   select 1 
   from INVENTTRANS x1 
   where x1.DATEPHYSICAL >= cast('2016-01-01' as date)
   and x1.ITEM_ID = t1.ITEM_ID
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

You need the older data from 2016-01-01 then

```
select ITEMID from INVENTTRANS itra where itra.DATEPHYSICAL < 
CONVERT(datetime, '2016-01-01')
```

Comment: "and not exist any newer" will not be satisfied here.